# resizing div height so it always fits the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm trying to make a DIV resize to always fit 90% of my page. I have a footer (.kontakt) that I'd like to always have positioned at the bottom of the screen, so I need my DIV to scale (if it's too big the footer won't move when I scroll). I am loading external html files onto my div using jquery, and the div always resizes to fit content. Problem is, I don't want to set max-height, min-height in css but would like for the div to resize every time the browser window resized.

Is there an easy solution to do that that I failed to find, and can I write a function that does that?
What event handler can I use that triggers on browser window resize?

I guess I could just use position:fixed on the footer(haven't actually tried if it works) but I'd prefer to have scrollbars on my div (hence overflow:auto;) than scrolling in the browser window. Thanks for the help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content').load('pages/test.html');
  console.log("content loaded");

  $(".kontakt").hover(
    function() {
      $(".kontakt").width("20%");
      $(".kontakt").css("margin-left", "40%");

      $(".kontakt").append("<a class='kontakttext'>mobitel: 031-535-919</a>");
      $(".kontakt").append("<br><a class='kontakttext'>stacionarni tel.: 01-3664-515</a><br>");
      $(".kontakt").append("<br><a class='kontakttext'>email: </a><a class='kontaktmail' href='mailto:sustersic_miha@hotmail.com'>sustersic_miha@hotmail.com</a><br>");
      $(".kontakt").append("<br><a class='kontakttext'>Visoko 19<br>1292 Ig<br>Slovenija</a>");
    },
    function() {
      $(".kontakt").empty();
      $(".kontakt").width("10%");
      $(".kontakt").css("margin-left", "45%");
      $(".kontakt").append("<div class='kontaktlabelbox'><div class='kontaktlabel'>Kontakt</div></div>");
    });
  $(".menubutton").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css("color", "#cccccc");
      $(this).prev().css("color", "#cccccc");
      $(this).next().css("color", "#cccccc");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
      $(this).prev().css("color", "#ffffff");
      $(this).next().css("color", "#ffffff");
    });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: verdana;
  background-image: url("images/background_test.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.topmenu {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000066;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.menubutton {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 2px;
}
.activatedmenubutton {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.menubreak {
  background-color: #000066;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px;
}
.kontaktlabel {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.kontaktlabelbox {
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.kontakttext {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.kontaktmail {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.kontakt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 45%;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Iščem delo</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="unicornsandrainbows.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="magic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <a class="menubreak" id="1">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="iz">Izobrazba</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="2">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="zn">Znanja in Kompetence</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="3">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="izk">Izkušnje</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="4">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="pč">Prosti Čas</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="5">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="fo">Fotografije</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="6">|</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="kontakt">
    <div class="kontaktlabelbox">
      <div class="kontaktlabel">Kontakt</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Honestly, I think CSS is your best route... Fix the footer as you say, set the height of your `div` to 90%, and also apply `overflow: scroll` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes `.contact` always have height equal to 90% of window height:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content').load('pages/test.html');
  console.log("content loaded");

  $(".kontakt").hover(
    function() {
      $(".kontakt").width("20%");
      $(".kontakt").css("margin-left", "40%");

      $(".kontakt").append("<a class='kontakttext'>mobitel: 031-535-919</a>");
      $(".kontakt").append("<br><a class='kontakttext'>stacionarni tel.: 01-3664-515</a><br>");
      $(".kontakt").append("<br><a class='kontakttext'>email: </a><a class='kontaktmail' href='mailto:sustersic_miha@hotmail.com'>sustersic_miha@hotmail.com</a><br>");
      $(".kontakt").append("<br><a class='kontakttext'>Visoko 19<br>1292 Ig<br>Slovenija</a>");
    },
    function() {
      $(".kontakt").empty();
      $(".kontakt").width("10%");
      $(".kontakt").css("margin-left", "45%");
      $(".kontakt").append("<div class='kontaktlabelbox'><div class='kontaktlabel'>Kontakt</div></div>");
    });
  $(".menubutton").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css("color", "#cccccc");
      $(this).prev().css("color", "#cccccc");
      $(this).next().css("color", "#cccccc");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
      $(this).prev().css("color", "#ffffff");
      $(this).next().css("color", "#ffffff");
    });

});

$(window).load(function() { $(window).trigger('resize') });

$(window).resize(function() {
   h = $(window).height() * 0.9;
   $('.content').css({'height': h + 'px'});
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: verdana;
  background-image: url("images/background_test.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.topmenu {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000066;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.menubutton {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 2px;
}
.activatedmenubutton {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.menubreak {
  background-color: #000066;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px;
}
.kontaktlabel {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.kontaktlabelbox {
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.kontakttext {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.kontaktmail {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.kontakt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 45%;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Iščem delo</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="unicornsandrainbows.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="magic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <a class="menubreak" id="1">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="iz">Izobrazba</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="2">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="zn">Znanja in Kompetence</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="3">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="izk">Izkušnje</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="4">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="pč">Prosti Čas</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="5">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="fo">Fotografije</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="6">|</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="kontakt">
    <div class="kontaktlabelbox">
      <div class="kontaktlabel">Kontakt</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: .content not contact but yeah, solution works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0):

@John Kapantzakis have already provided a solution but i will try to give you a non js solution here! ~ let me know if you want to understand the trick. P.S this solution do-sent keep layout exactly at 90% but enough that footer have its own negative area. Go on play with it and let me know if it is what you wanted.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: verdana;
  background-image: url("images/background_test.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.topmenu {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000066;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.menubutton {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 2px;
}
.activatedmenubutton {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.menubreak {
  background-color: #000066;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px;
}
.kontaktlabel {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.kontaktlabelbox {
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.kontakttext {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  background-color: #000066;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.kontaktmail {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.kontakt {
    background-color: #000066;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #cccccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    padding: 0 7px;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
}
body, html{ height: 100%; }
.t-layout{ display: table; width: 100% }
.t-layout--full{ height: 100%; }
.t-row{ display: table-row; }
.t-col{ display: table-cell; }
.t-col--top{ vertical-align: top; }
.t-col--mid{ vertical-align: middle; }
.t-col--bot{ vertical-align: bottom; }
.t-col--compress{ height: 1px; }
.t-a-c{ text-align: center; }
.content-wrap{ position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; overflow-y: auto;}
.relative{ position: relative; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Iščem delo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="unicornsandrainbows.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="magic.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="t-layout t-layout--full">
      <div class="t-row">
        <div class="t-col t-col--compress">
          <div class="topmenu">
            <a class="menubreak" id="1">|</a
                    ><a class="menubutton" id="iz">Izobrazba</a
                    ><a class="menubreak" id="2">|</a
                    ><a class="menubutton" id="zn">Znanja in Kompetence</a
                    ><a class="menubreak" id="3">|</a
                    ><a class="menubutton" id="izk">Izkušnje</a
                    ><a class="menubreak" id="4">|</a
                    ><a class="menubutton" id="pč">Prosti Čas</a
                    ><a class="menubreak" id="5">|</a
                    ><a class="menubutton" id="fo">Fotografije</a
                    ><a class="menubreak" id="6">|</a>
          </div>
        </div><!--.t-col -->
      </div><!--.t-row -->
      <div class="t-row">
        <div class="t-col t-col--top relative">
          <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--.t-col -->
      </div><!--.t-row -->
      <div class="t-row">
        <div class="t-col t-a-c t-col--bot t-col--compress">
          <div class="kontakt">
            <div class="kontaktlabelbox">
              <div class="kontaktlabel">Kontakt</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--.t-col -->
      </div><!--.t-row -->
    </div><!--.t-layout -->
  </body>

</html>
```